# Correct way to check the type of an expression in Roslyn analyzer?

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, roslyn

I'm writing a code analyzer with Roslyn, and I need to check if an `ExpressionSyntax` is of type `Task` or `Task<T>`.

So far I have this:

```
private static bool IsTask(ExpressionSyntax expression, SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var type = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(expression).Type;
    if (type == null)
        return false;
    if (type.Equals(context.SemanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Threading.Tasks.Task")))
        return true;
    if (type.Equals(context.SemanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1")))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

It works for `Task`, but not for `Task<int>` or `Task<string>`... I could check the name and namespace, but it's impractical because I have to check each "level" of the namespace.

Is there a recommended way to do it?

Comment: I had almost the same question, but more genericly: How to check if a Expression matches any given Type, not a specific type like in this question. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33994426/3568661) with full code sample here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check whether the type [is a generic type](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs,30), and, if it is, use [`OriginalDefinition`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs,96) to return the unconstructed generic type.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed the fact that the `ITypeInfo` I was getting was actually a `INamedTypeSymbol`, so I couldn't see the `IsGeneric` property. However `ConstructUnboundGenericType` gives me `Task<>`, rather than `Task<TResult>`, so it doesn't match with the type I get with `GetTypeFromMetadataName`. I had to use the [`ConstructedFrom`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamedTypeSymbol.cs,2b034eb9d8cd5598) property instead.

Comment: Use `OriginalDefinition` -- it'll give you the type that would match GetTypeByMetadataName in all cases. In nested generic or generic method cases ConstructedFrom isn't quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need Symbols rather than Syntax

```
INamedTypeSymbol nulable = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Nullable`1");
INamedTypeSymbol int32 = compilation.GetSpecialType(SpecialType.System_Int32);
INamedTypeSymbol nulableInt = nulable.Construct(int32);
```