# How to compare a Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ITypeSymbol to a System.Type

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have successfully received an ITypeSymbol from a SyntaxNode by using:

```
SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(sytaxNode).ConvertedType
```

Now I would like to know if this `ITypeSymbol` corresponds to a `System.Type` instance that is present in my executing code, like `typeof(IEnumerable<int>)` or `someObject.GetType()`.

I tried

```
typeInfo.ConvertedType.ToString() == type.ToString()
```

But these do not use the same formatting rules, for instance for generics like `IEnumerable<int>`

`TypeInfo.ToString() == "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>"`

while

```
typeof(IEnumerable<int>).ToString() == "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]"
```

Moreover I think it would be better to compare AssemblyQualifiedNames in stead of just the Namespace and type name to avoid possible name clashes.

Ideally I would like to be able to get the actual System.Type instance in my executing code that corresponds to the ITypeInfo I got from the semantic model (provided that the required assembly is loaded and/or available). That would allow checking if the type is assignable from some other type etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo() for ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax.Type returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27535382/semanticmodel-gettypeinfo-for-objectcreationexpressionsyntax-type-returns-null)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that question is about how to get the TypeInfo, this Question is about how to compare the TypeInfo to a Type

Comment: If you can get the TypeInfo I thought that you should be able to compare but perhaps I am mistaken maybe my understanding relates to this link in regards to your last comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240167/correct-way-to-check-the-type-of-an-expression-in-roslyn-analyzer

Comment: That still does not answer the question how to compare it to a System.Type instance

Comment: what does the `System.Type` you are trying to compare look like .. can you not use the `System.Type.Equals` Method

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the `INamedTypeSymbol` for a type name with `Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName()`.

So try this:

```
semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(sytaxNode).ConvertedType.Equals(
  semanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(WhateverType).FullName))
```

This won't work with closed generic types, for those you'll need to do a bit more. For example:

```
var ienumerableType = semanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1");
var intType = semanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.Int32");
var type = ienumerableType.Construct(intType);
```

Comment: Indeed this does the trick, a more generic solution would require some recursion this way but should be doable I think

Comment: Well, I'm getting null for ienumerableType and intType, any ideas why?

Comment: It might make sense to use the property `Type` instead of `ConvertedType` on the `TypeInfo` object. For example, if a string is assigned to an object property, the `ConvertedType` will be object and not string. In my application, this led to an unexpected error.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the answer from @Tamas, I created the following recursive solution that works for closed generic types.

```
    static bool TypeSymbolMatchesType(ITypeSymbol typeSymbol, Type type, SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {
        return GetTypeSymbolForType(type, semanticModel).Equals(typeSymbol);
    }

    static INamedTypeSymbol GetTypeSymbolForType(Type type, SemanticModel semanticModel)
    {

        if (!type.IsConstructedGenericType)
        {
            return semanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(type.FullName);
        }

        // get all typeInfo's for the Type arguments 
        var typeArgumentsTypeInfos = type.GenericTypeArguments.Select(a => GetTypeSymbolForType(a, semanticModel));

        var openType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        var typeSymbol = semanticModel.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(openType.FullName);
        return typeSymbol.Construct(typeArgumentsTypeInfos.ToArray<ITypeSymbol>());
    }
```